# How to get amazon SNS when a large file is uploaded to a S3 folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I was able to set up an SNS notification for a specific file type in a folder on Amazon S3 but I want to restrict the notification emails to be sent only when the file size is bigger than 90MB.

How will I do that?

Comment: Is this using S3 event notifications?

Comment: it is using topic notification (Simple Notification Service) https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v3/home?region=us-east-1#/topics

Comment: Have you considered a small Lambda to do this?  There isn't a way to filter by size.  A small Lambda would get the notification, check the size (using the HeadObject API), and send *another* notification via SNS when the size is greater than 90MB.

Comment: I were able to do it with Amazon EventBridge by creating a new rule : https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/events/home?region=us-east-1#/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with Amazon EventBridge by creating a new rule and adding this Event pattern and linking it to my SNS topic

```html
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["BUCKETNAME"]
    },
    "object": {
      "size": [{
        "numeric": [">=", 90000000]
      }],
      "key": [{
        "prefix": "folderPath"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's rather neat! I would normally have suggested using an AWS Lambda function, but being able to filter the events in EventBridge is a nice solution. Where in the flow did you insert the EventBridge Rule? Did you configure Amazon S3 to send the event to the Amazon SNS Topic, and then have SNS filter which messages get sent out? How was EventBridge involved in that?